# Need help determining source of bug in small C# number to percentile conversion program

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to programming in general but have been working with Java for the past 2-3 months and decided to take a crack at C# on the side just for fun because I heard they were similar. The problem I'm having with this program, which is just a way for someone to convert an int to a percentage, is that it takes all my input correctly but the percentage always shows up as zero! For example, there are two input prompts: one that asks you for a number for converting and one that asks you what the number is out of. After both prompts the program displays correctly "Your percentage is: " and then just writes 0 no matter what numbers I use for input, help please!

[code]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NumToPercentage
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int userScore, userTotalScore, userPercentage;
        string userInput, userTotal;


        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the number to percentile conversion program!");

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your number here: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        userScore = int.Parse(userInput); 

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter what the number is out of (i.e. 100, 42, 37, etc.): ");
        userTotal = Console.ReadLine();
        userTotalScore = int.Parse(userTotal);

        userPercentage = (userScore/userTotalScore)*100; 

        Console.WriteLine("Your percentage is: " + userPercentage); 
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

[/code]

Comment: Did you bother to step thru the program with the debugger? Hint userPercentage needs to be a Decimal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is integer math, it rounds towards zero.

- 1 divided by 100 is 0.
- 99 divided by 100 is 0.
- 199 divided by 100 is 1.

Convert at least one of the operands to a floating point type (double, float, decimal) when you perform your calculation.

```
double result = ((double)x / y) * 100;
```

If needed, you can always cast the result back to an integer if you are uninterested in the decimal places.

```
int finalPercent = (int)result;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony, it seems so obvious now in retrospect! Don't know why I thought int was a good idea but live and learn right? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
userPercentage = (int)((double)userScore/userTotalScore)*100);
```

or

```
userPercentage = (userScore * 100) / userTotalScore;
```

int/int is an integer division and only returns the whole part which is always 0 for a percentage, which then multiplied by 0 equals... 0

Answer (score 2):

> (userScore/userTotalScore)*100;

dividing two integers will result in an integer value. It chops off the fraction.

Instead, do this

```
(int)( ( (double) userScore )/userTotalScore)*100 );
```

By utilizing type casting, you can get the result you are looking for.

Comment: double / int returns a double, so you don't need to cast both values.

Comment: Edited for @rsbarro's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare your vars as `int`, you're performing an integer division.

You need to declare `userPercentage` as a `double` instead of `int` and cast the `userScore` and `userTotalScore` to `double` before performing the division.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use decimals instead of ints. Integer division behaves different than floating point division.

Change your declarations to:

```
decimal userScore, userTotalScore, userPercentage;
```

And then later:

```
userScore = decimal.Parse(userInput);
```

And

```
userTotalScore = decimal.Parse(userTotal);
```